# Spark - ElasticSearch Index creation performance too slow

Tags: scala, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am trying to use Apache spark to create an index in Elastic search(Writing huge data to ES).I have done a Scala program to create index using Apache spark.I have to index huge data, which is getting as my product bean in a LinkedList. Then.Then i tried to traverse over the product bean list and create the index. My code given below.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ESIndex").setMaster("local[*]")
    conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true").set("es.nodes", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("es.port", "9200")
      .set("es.http.timeout", "5m")
      .set("es.scroll.size", "100")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    //Return my product bean as a in a linkedList.
    val list: util.LinkedList[product] = getData() 

    for (item <- list) {
      sc.makeRDD(Seq(item)).saveToEs("my_core/json")
    }
```

The issue with this approach is taking too much time to create the index.
Is there any way to create the index in a better way?

Comment: Why do you pass data through driver? This is an obvious bottleneck.

Comment: plus if your data fits in memory why to overhead your architecture with spark ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't pass data through driver unless it is necessary. Depending on what is the source of data returned from `getData` you should use relevant input method or create your own. If data comes from MongoDB use for example [`mongo-hadoop`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop), [`Spark-MongoDB`](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB) or Drill with JDBC connection. Then use `map` or similar method to build the required objects and use `saveToEs` on transformed RDD.
2. Creating a RDD with as single element doesn't make sense. It doesn't benefit from Spark architecture at all. You just start a potentially huge number of tasks which have nothing with only a single active executor.

Comment: so is there way to process the entire list than a single object through driver?

Comment: Once again. Don't use driver to pass or process the data. If you do it, and process data locally there is no reason to use Spark.